# Updating a table from another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a temp table which I want to use to update my other table. Below is the code

```
UPDATE custompricingtest t1, custompricingtesttemp t2 
SET t1.customerName = t2.customerName
WHERE t1.partnumberSKU = t2.partnumberSKU
```

Both table has around 14k records, it takes around 10 mins to run this query. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Do you have an index on `partnumberSKU` in each table?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create an index on each:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_sku1 ON custompricingtest (partnumberSKU);
CREATE INDEX idx_sku2 ON custompricingtesttemp (partnumberSKU);
```

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes is taking too long time, how about this ?

```
UPDATE custompricingtest
SET t1.customerName = 
(select custompricingtesttemp.customerName
 WHERE custompricingtesttemp.partnumberSKU = custompricingtest.partnumberSKU)
```

and you can create index on both

- custompricingtest.partnumberSKU
- custompricingtesttemp.partnumberSKU